# C# WPF display images like a grid

Tags: c#, json, wpf, image, grid

Im a total C#/programming beginner.

I try to display alot of pictures like an album or grid like.

It looks like this so far: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaESP.jpg

But there are empty places and when I scroll down it looks even worse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKMas.png

I created a UniformGrid inside a ScrollViewer. That was the easiest way for me to get what I want. Maybe not the best solution. If I add more pictures the images are getting smaller. I think thats cause of the uniform grid.

Here are two code example how I did that.

js.movie1 is an object which contains a few members. js.movie1[0].poster is the file name of the first picture (there are 275 pictures).
This object is created by the JSON.NET framework. It just reads a JSON file set some variables and I put the object in a list.
for example js.movie1[0].poster is the file name of the poster as a picture, js.movie1[0].title is the title of the movie and so on.

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uGrid.Children.Clear();
        string strWebAdress = @"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"; 



        for (int i = 0; i < js.movie1.Count; i++)

        {


            Image img = new Image();
            BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strWebAdress + js.movie1[i].poster));


            //bimg.sou
            img.BeginInit();
            img.Source = bimg;
            img.EndInit();

            uGrid.Children.Add(img);
        }
```

Or I did this:

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uGrid.Children.Clear();
        string strWebAdress = @"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"; 

        List<string> listImage = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*jpg").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName).ToList();
        List<Image> imgList = new List<Image>();

        for (int i = 0; i < js.movie1.Count; i++)

        {
            Image Controlimage = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strCoverUrl + js.movie1[i].poster)),

            };


            uGrid.Children.Add(Controlimage);
        }
```

My problem is that there are empty spaces between some pictures, I cant resize them like I want. And I want to scroll while the program is loading the pictures.
The program needs 1,5 GB of Ram and alot of CPU power so I need a betetr solution for this.

With Foreach I can scroll but I created a array for that. I dont know how to count in foreach with a object. Atleast not in the way my object is used.

There have to be a way to load and display pictures from an URL which doesnt block the UI and needs so much power. 
Like I said Im a bloody beginner ;)

Greetings Fabian :)

Comment: You can use async, instead of constructing your bitmaps directly from an URI, download the images with a WebClient and using await DownloadDataTaskAsync, you will get a byte array what can be used to instantiate a MemoryStream and then construct the bitmap with that stream, that will not block the UI, Also, you can combine that with a Parallel.For to use multiple threads. And about the memory, you must unload the images which aren't on screen, you can cache the images to disk in this way if it's already cached then you can create them from disk instead from the remote source.

Comment: This is not a simple task for a beginner, you will need to read a lot of info.

Comment: Honestly... i would ditch the data grid idea and go with a horizontal listview with custom item templates

Comment: You should also reduce the bitmap size to the required minimum during creation of th BitmapImages, by setting their DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight property.

Comment: Keep the UniformGrid, but put it in the ItemsPanel of a ListBox. Then bind (or assign) the ItemsSource property of the ListBox to an `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>` where you add your BitmapImages. ListBox supports virtualization, so it may help with unloading invisible images.